# How to store DOM style property in variable

Tags: javascript

I have this code here:

```
function slideUp(elem,num,speed,lim){
    var pos = document.getElementById(elem).style.top
    var moveUp = num
    if(lim != pos){
        var int = setInterval(function(){
            moveUp = moveUp-100;
            document.getElementById(elem).style.top=+moveUp+"px";
        },speed)
    }else if(lim == pos){
        clearInterval(int);
    }   
}
```

The problem that i am having is the "pos" variable does not hold a value. I want it to hold the top position of an element that i specify

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that `document.getElementById(elem).style.top` does not have a value, and thus `pos` does not have a value.

You need to calculate the property yourself. You need to use `currentStyle` / `getComputedStyle` as the `style.top` value can come from CSS or can be implicitly defined.

From: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html

```
function getStyle(el,styleProp)
{
    var x = document.getElementById(el);
    if (x.currentStyle)
        var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}
```

Use like:

```
var top = getStyle(document.getElementById(elem), 'top');
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading directly from the style object doesn't often work because it's only populated if you set those values from JavaScript. To get values that are set from HTML or CSS, use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) to query the actual applied style of the element.

See this example from the Mozilla documentation:

```
function getTheStyle() {
    var elem= document.getElementById("elem_container");
    var theCSSprop= window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("height");
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= theCSSprop;
}
```

Comment: IE prior to IE9 does not support getComputedStyle and you need to use currentStyle as in Frits' example. IE9 now supports getComputedStyle.

Answer (score 0):

There are two completely different problems I see here:

1. That "int" variable is declared as a local variable to that function, which means that once an invocation of the function has set up an interval timer, nothing will be able to clear it because the value will have been lost. You could make the variable global, I suppose.
2. Most probably, you're not getting a "top" position because there is no style information directly available from the element itself. If the style comes from CSS or by basic browser layout, the "style" property won't tell you about that.

Getting the style is kind-of a pain, and it's different in IE than in other browsers. Mr. van Campen's answer describes how to get it.

Oh, and find the semicolon key on your keyboard :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function slideUp(elem,num,speed,lim){
    var pos = document.getElementById(elem).style.top
    var moveUp = num
    if(lim != pos){
        var int = setInterval(function(){
            moveUp = moveUp-100;
            pos += moveUp;
            document.getElementById(elem).style.top=pos+"px";
        },speed)
    } else if(lim == pos) {
        clearInterval(int);
    }   
}
```